# Is there a way to hide as a spoiler some part of sensitive information in files in VS Code, like stars in a password

Tags: visual-studio-code, privacy

I share my desktop, so I don't want to overly expose my tokens while I am showing off how I code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a possibility to display text with stars. But in VS Code you can, depending on which language you are using, collapse certain parts of your code. For instance, in C# you can type this:

```
#region sensitive
const string Token = "blah";
#endregion
```

Clicking on the arrow symbol in the margin, will collapse the region to this (note the line numbers):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Secret Manager in Cloud Code for VS Code

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager

With Cloud Code's Secret Manager integration, you can create, view, update, and use secrets in your IDE and without storing them in your codebase.

You can use the same trick with API keys btw.

https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/secret-manager

Comment: I added the secret in Cloud Code, but I don't know how to use it.
Previously I configured the `.vscode/launch.json` to include the secret exposing it's value there, and put `.vscode` in my .gitignore. But I don't want to open launch.json and see my secret there. So how do I use this secret in Cloud Code, and pass it to my program that currently reads the environment variable set in `launch.json`. It's a rust program and read like this:
`    let token = env::var("DISCORD_TOKEN").expect("Expected a token in the environment");
`

Comment: Hm looks like they dont support Rust. Personally what I do is I keep the API keys in a text file in an encypted container and read the textfile from my program.

Comment: Apart from Rust code, I couldn't figure out a way to write a script that reads from cloud API, sets an environment variable so I can read it from Rust without changing the existing Rust code. Finally, Integrate this into VS Code as part of a build step in `launch.json`.

Comment: In other languages reading from the cloud and using the result looks like this: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-secret-version#secretmanager-access-secret-version-python They don't set an env it just ends up as a variable.

Comment: For example using the api this command is suggested:
`curl "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/secrets/secret-id/versions/version-id:access" \
    --request "GET" \
    --header "authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    --header "content-type: application/json"
`

As you can see it needs the `gcloud` cli to print access token, where I have installed `gcloud` but gcloud is not available on a terminal I start from VS Code. The whole thing is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to go about it.

### Reconsider your practices

When showing your code, you should never need to show private data in the 1st place. It is often kept in e.g. `.env` files available only locally that noone needs to look at as they're just a bunch of constants that bring no value for rating your coding skills.

Here's a random [article](https://blog.gitguardian.com/secrets-api-management/) about this topic that was one of 1st results in Google and covers the topics well.

### Use a repository-level solution

[git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) is an example of software that will keep your files secure on top of the above note, if they e.g. get to a repository or you show them live by mistake. You can temporarily `git-crypt lock` to make them unreadable. Of course you need to remember to do that before sharing your desktop.

A more VSCode solution is e.g. [Cloak](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-cloak) extension, which hides `.env` vars with a command that you could autoexecute based on some conditions or with a keyboard shortcut.

**Update**: there's also [Dotenv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dotenv.dotenv-vscode) extension that has multiple ways of dealing with it, including simple one click autohiding in `.env` files.

### If you really need to keep secrets scattered around files

You really don't.

There aren't also many good and universal solutions, as e.g. marking vulnerable lines with comments differs per programming language. This [auto-collapse-blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=allergan-bt.auto-collapse-blocks) or anything like that could work for instance, but I definitely can't recommend this process.